# how to find if a host is a physical server or a virtual server

Tags: virtual-machines

I am actually trying to find if a given host is a physical server or a virtual machine. I searched on Google but couldn't find any commands or tools. Can anyone here let me know is there is any utility which can tell me if its a physical server or a virtual server.

Comment: Um...the hardware would tell you.

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: @Michael its for linux os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dmidecode` can help you:

```
dennis@seahawk:~$ sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer
Dell Inc.
dennis@mirage:~$ sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer
Red Hat
```

The second one is a KVM instance. You can detect vmware/xen etc. this way too.

Answer (score 1):

On windows platforms we run the CPUID program from here http://www.cpuid.com/

The Motherboard is shown as "Intel Corporation 440BX Desktop Reference Platform"

```
DMI Baseboard       
vendor          Intel Corporation
model           440BX Desktop Reference Platform
```